# How to copy directory with xcopy?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xcopy

I am using **Visual Studio 2012.**

I have the following **xcopy command**

```
set myDir="$(SolutionDir)\MyFolder\MySubfolder"
xcopy /D /Y /I /G /R /E %myDir% "$(TargetDir)"
```

This only copies the contents of **MySubfolder** to the **TargetDir**. But I want it to create the whole folder.

- Right now if I have:

  > MySubfolder\file1
  >
  > MySubfolder\file2
- And with my command **I get:**

  > $(TargetDir)\file1
  >
  > $(TargetDir)\file2
- **I want:**

  > $(TargetDir)\MySubfolder\file1
  >
  > $(TargetDir)\MySubfolder\file2

I've tried several xcopy parameters but none seems to work.

Is there a way to accomplish this with **xcopy**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do as follows:

```
set myDir="$(SolutionDir)\MyFolder\MySubfolder"
xcopy /D /Y /I /G /R /E %myDir% "$(TargetDir)\MySubfolder"
```

Include the folder you want in the target directory also.